# I want to import text file to table in mySQL and show in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to import text file to table in mySQL and show in php

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "schedule");
    if($connection){
        $query1 = LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "practice.txt" INTO TABLE schedule.assigned_classes;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM schedule.assigned_classes";
}
```

but it doesn't work. May you help me?

Comment: Please format your question in a readable way.

Comment: What should work, but does not yet?

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute sql, you must call `mysqli_query()` function

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "schedule");
    if($connection){
        $query1 = LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "practice.txt" INTO TABLE schedule.assigned_classes;    
         mysqli_query($con,$query1);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM schedule.assigned_classes";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
       ...
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: This is my whole code: <?php 
  $connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "schedule");
  if($connection)
  {
   $query1 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/practice.txt" INTO TABLE schedule.assigned_classes"; 
   mysqli_query($connection, $query1);

   $query = "SELECT * FROM schedule.assigned_classes";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
   
       if($result){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         echo $row['id'] ;

Comment: But, the problem is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" INTO TABLE schedule.assigned' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: Check your practice.txt file format. and check you "load file" sql format.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html